# Spritekit bodywithbodies using Swift exception

Tags: ios, swift

I've just started teaching myself some swift and am trying to create a 3-sided box with a concave physics body. I am using an image for the side, and using the same image for the other side and the base. I've assigned each with a position and added to the view, but when using the bodyWithBodies method, I get the following Log error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKSpriteNode _shapes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78737140'

with message 'Thread 1: SIGABRT' at the AppDelegate class.

If someone could let me know what the issue is, then I'd be very grateful.

Here's my code:

```
    let side1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "430x30.png")
    side1.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
    side1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 - 100 ,y: self.size.height/2 - 100)

    side1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: side1.size)

    self.addChild(side1)

    let side2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "430x30.png")
    side2.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
    side2.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 + 100,y: self.size.height/2 - 100)

    side2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: side2.size)

    self.addChild(side2)


    let base = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "30x430.png")
    base.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0)
    base.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 - 100,y: self.size.height/2 - 100)

    base.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: base.size)

    self.addChild(base)


    let box = SKPhysicsBody(bodies:[base,side1,side2])

    box.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Box // 3
    box.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None // 4
    box.dynamic = false
```

Thanks,

Foot

Answer (score 0):

The method to create a physics body from a collection of bodies requires an array of physics body objects; you are passing it an array of sprites. To fix this issue, change the method call to

```
let box = SKPhysicsBody(bodies:[base.physicsBody,side1.physicsBody,side2.physicsBody])
```